# .emacs configuration overridden when starting emacs

Tags: emacs

When I edit a file with `emacs`, the configuration stored in the `.emacs` file is read (I can judge this by the font size). However, not a second passes and both the window and font sizes decrease. It seems that my custom configuration is being overridden. I don't know where this additional configuration is stored.

System: Light Ubuntu 18.04

My `.emacs` file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(setq tab-stop-list t))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foundry "PfEd" :slant normal :weight normal :height 143 :width normal)))))

; disable the wellcome screen
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

;; rebind C-x C-b to invoke buffer-menu rather than list-buffers
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'buffer-menu)

; open list of buffers in active window
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'buffer-menu)

; Directory to place the backup files
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.emacs.d/backup_files")))

; Disable Large file size warning
(setq large-file-warning-threshold nil)

;; show line numbers
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

Comment: Do you have a `~/.Xdefaults` file mentioning Emacs configuration?

Comment: No, I don't have a `~/.Xdefaults` or a `~/.Xresources` file

Comment: I am on Arch Linux, so likely a different issue. But due to a bug (I really can't remember where), I was unable to set the emacs font size in emacs (font size settings in my .emacs had no effect). I had to go around it by setting it in my `.Xresources` file with `emacs*font: inconsolata-12`. It's been a while, so I imagine that you have found a solution by now. But if not, you could always create an `.Xresources` file and set the font in it.

Comment: @prosoitos I followed your prescription but it did had no effect. I have not found when or how my .emacs settings are being overriden :(

Comment: Sounds like you have a `custom.el` with font/face settings in it.

Comment: My bad: your problem is different: as you rightly wrote, something seems to indeed be overriding your setting. In my case, nothing was overriding it, it could not be set in emacs in the first place (again, I forgot what the cause was).

Comment: Note (just in case): I imagine that you rebooted after writing the `.Xresources` file? If you don't, you have to run `xrdb path/to/.Xresources` so that the changes take effect.

Comment: yes! update with `xrdb` did the trick :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [@prosoitos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9210961/prosoitos) advice from the comment's section in the original question:

- created $HOME/.Xresouces file containing the following line
  `emacs*font: DejaVu Sans Mono 16`
- in the terminal, type `xrdb $HOME/.Xresouces`